# Bootstrap tooltip with knockout.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

im finding it hard to find a way to apply the bootstrap tooltip to my img once knockout has finsihed rendering a for loop.

The following shows the correct image, and the "standard" html tooltip shows up, but the bootstrap tooltip isnt activated by the .tooltip() call.

Where am i going wrong?

**Viewmodel**

```
self.handleAfterRender= function(elements, data) {
    $(elements).find('img').tooltip();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-bind="with: $root.SelectedSubmission">
  <div data-bind="foreach: {data: To, afterRender: handleAfterRender}">
    <div class="pull-left">
      <img class="mediumprofileimage" rel="tooltip" 
           data-bind="attr: {src: ProfilePicture, alt: Fullname, title: Fullname}" />
      <br/>
      <span data-bind="text: Fullname"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

I found a little bit more out about the problem. it seems like the element is loosing the binding to `tooltip()`. I am not sure if I have to use the `jquery.on()` or `.live()` somehow to keep the binding alive.

Comment: M.b. you could create some kind of example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 1):

you can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875773/bootstraps-tooltip-not-working-with-knockout-bindings-w-fiddle) or try [Knockout-bootstrap](https://github.com/billpull/knockout-bootstrap) it's a good option

Comment: Thanks! This is a more universal fix (and much more KO-friendly) than having to set up afterRender events (I'd rather my foreach loops not have to know to do things because some template nested within them happens to require some jquery/bootstrap JS code)

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should use foreach, because **afterRender** got an array of the inserted DOM elements:

`$(elements).each(function(index,element){ $(element).find('img').tooltip()});`

But I think it is better to use **afterAdd** event instead of **afterRender**, because you need to add tooltip for each added item, and then you will be able to work with each item separately like you trying to work now:

> $(element).find('img').tooltip();

Link to KnockoutJs documentation about **[Post-processing or animating the generated DOM elements](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note_5_postprocessing_or_animating_the_generated_dom_elements)**

Comment: thanks for the input.  i tried the afteradd, but with no success.  i believe that $(elements).find('img').tooltip(); has the same effect as the .each way. i have found out a little bit more info, which i have posted in the question