# Jquery tooltip to use knockout observable as content

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, tooltip

It was using jquery ui tooltip like this

```
self.variable=ko.observable("a");
 $(document).uitooltip({
//some settings
content: self.variable();
})
//Some event here which would update self.variable
```

The idea is by clicking a button inside of the tooltip, the self.variable would be updated and the content of tooltip would change. But  while the variable would change, so far, i am not able to have it updated immediately. I have to hover in and out again to see updated content. What approach should I use?

--Update--

A example of the problem

http://jsfiddle.net/32b1n6p5/1/

What I want is that when I hover the first input--->the tooltip show up--->type anything--->tooltip change. But right now, I have to hover out and in again to see the change

Comment: Can you share your knockout binding on tooltip ?

Comment: You can create a custom binding handler for tooltip like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16876013